# Force Qt5 to load SSL dlls from exe dir

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, qt5

**Update** Sorry, guys, I was incorrectly determined the problem. All is working, error was in "other program logic". Please delete or close the question.

Qt5 is designed to load `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` on program start before any instruction in `main()` (because it is static).

(**Details**: it is located in `qtbase\src\network\ssl\qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp`:

```
static QPair<QSystemLibrary*, QSystemLibrary*> loadOpenSslWin32()
```

)

Issue:

- my program starts with not its exe dir as working directory
- `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` resides in its exe dir
- user cannot install OpenSSL in system dir
- user cannot change PATH variable
- I cannot recompile Qt, i.e. ship program with static Qt compiled with openssl-linked

Qt loads searches dlls in this order (from `qtbase\src\corelib\plugin\qsystemlibrary.cpp`):

1. Application path.
2. System libraries path.
3. Trying all paths inside the PATH environment variable.

No. 1 is Application path, but in fact it does not search there.

My program:

```
int main()
{
    // at this point Qt5 already checked and tried to load the DLLs

    // so this:

    ChangeCurrentWorkingDirectoryToExeDir(); // some function to change cwd to current exe dir 

    // does not work :-(

    // ... other program logic ..
}
```

How to force Qt5 to reload OpenSSL DLLs after changing working directory?
May be someone already faced this problem...

**Update** Sorry, guys, I was incorrectly determined the problem. All is working, error was in "other program logic". Please delete or close the question.

Comment: why don't you start the application from the exe dir as working dir?

Comment: @m.s. it is started as URI protocol handler (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en_us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx), it is not possible to specify working dir

Comment: ok, but why don't can't you recompile Qt? and why is the PATH variable unmodifiable?

Comment: Well the function is static but that does not mean it is executing that function, this you still have to do by yourself.

Comment: @m.s. I think it is possible, but is it really not possible to do it with a little blood?

Comment: How are you deploying the app?  Are you using windeployqt?

Comment: If Qt would load the libraries from the working directory, that'd be a security issue (on could inject other DLLs). I don't see why the dir of the executable shouldn't work though, that's the usual location where one puts the files.

Comment: Why do you think it is because of OpenSSL? What is the error?

Comment: **Update** Sorry, guys, I was incorrectly determined the problem. All is working, error was in "other program logic". Please delete or close the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QSystemLibrary::load` is called with `onlySystemDirectory = false` for SSL, so `QFileInfo(qAppFileName()).path()` is the first place where the DLLs are searched. Search order:

1. application dir
2. system path (e.g. C:\Windows\System32)
3. all paths in PATH

I don't find documentation for that, but in our software, Qt finds SSL `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` when they are in the same directory as the application .exe, given that

- the .dll files are not in PATH
- the .dll files are not in the working directory
- no [qt.conf](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html) exists

If you have a `qt.conf`, the default library value might apply, which is `.\lib`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after lot of debugging I found that openssl DLLs loaded correctly, error was in other place of program.

Answer (score 1):

Library search orders are discussed on MSDN at [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There's a few ways to handle loading libraries, but it sounds like most of them won't apply.

Its not clear to me why you can call `ChangeCurrentWorkingDirectoryToExeDir`, but you can't call [`SetDllDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm probably missing something obvious.

It seems like your last option is to create an `Qt.exe.local` file. This is called [Dynamic-Link Library Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and will cause the linker to load the DLL specified in the local file.

Comment: I think this does not apply in this case because SSL is loaded at runtime, not at application load time. This can be confirmed using the Dependency Walker. I can properly start an app using Qt Network with no libeay32.dll/ssleay32.dll available which causes runtime warnings like `QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init`.